# Employment Non-disclosure Agreement

Tags: hiring, europe, non-disclosure-agreement

I am considering changing positions, so I went to an interview and they liked me. That's it.

Now here is the problem, I asked them to see the contract of my employment, and they said that I first have to sign a NDA with them, because their contracts were an object of Authors' rights.

Should I be suspicious, or is this normal for the modern workplace ?

[EDIT]
Yes, they did make me an offer, i have not verbally agreed to it yet, because i wanted to first read the contract.

Comment: Did they actually make you an offer?

Comment: Yes, they did .

Comment: What is the big deal if the NDA is you cannot disclose the contract?

Comment: I have seen this on occasion in the USA, doesn't seem odd to me.

Comment: Should have included this above, did you accept the offer?  I wouldn't expect to see a contract  until I at least verbally accepted the offer.  Until you have committed to them they may not want to share that information

Comment: Be sure the NDA is appropriately limited in scope.  I'd also want to see the employee handbook before accepting, as well.  Engage an attorney if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be suspicious, ... ?

Probably not.

> or is this normal for the modern workplace ?

Sometimes, but usually completely unnecessary. Many companies are completely over the top in such matters. Author's rights would normally be covered by copyright, anyway.

However, you MUST be allowed to obtain legal advice concerning your contract of employment!

Comment: Yes, not unusual to require an NDA to see the contract.  It may contain clauses that vary from person to person, or be different than competitors and they do not want those details shared.  Yes, lawyer confidentiality should be an exception to the NDA, but that would be for profession legal opinion bound by confidentiality, not armchair lawyers offering an opinion not bound in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

> Now here is the problem, I asked them to see the contract of my
>   employment, and they said that I first have to sign a NDA with them,
>   because their contracts were an object of Authors' rights.
>
> Should I be suspicious, or is this normal for the modern workplace ?

There's nothing to be suspicious of here.

Read the NDA. If you don't understand it, run it by your lawyer first. (Never sign a document you don't understand.)

If it doesn't meet your needs, don't sign it and move on to seek offers from different companies.

If the NDA is okay, then sign it and start reviewing the contract.